# Replacement of Bea Tuxedo

Tags: bea, tuxedo

We are using Bea Tuxedo 8.1 in one of our application. So now we are planning for replacement of Tuxedo due to cost saving . So if any one know the best suitable replacement option for Tuxedo please let me know.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042727/cost-saving-alternatives-to-oracle-tuxedo

Comment: Hi,

Will it be support FML/CSL also if i am going to the option Enduro/X. Because we are using FML/CSL (To connect client and server connectivity) and backend logics are written in Pro*C.

Can you let me know of below options are support.

Red Hat JBoss Enterprise Application Platform.
Apache Tomcat.
Apache Server.
Nginx.
IBM WebSphere Application Server.
IIS 7.5.
Tornado.
Apache Geronimo.

Comment: Enduro/X supports FML. Their version of FML is called "UBF". However fml.h and fml32.h are there with almost 100% compatibility.